# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} (n+1)^{\frac 23} -(n-1)^{\frac 23}$

Tags: limits

Clearly, $\infty -\infty \not =0$

I have a feeling the squeeze theorem can be applied here, but I am not sure how to write the required terms separately. Can I get a hint?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/256806/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2038809/42969 for a similar problem. Those solutions can be applied here as well.

Comment: Have you thought of writing it as $(a-b)(a+b)=(a^2-b^2)$? I suggest trying this things might cancel

Comment: If you follow the question by @MartinR, and trying that Difference of Squares it might be worth while.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky That wouldn't be a good idea, as it's not correct. And the correct $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ doesn't help, much.

Comment: @ProfessorVector You get the expression down to $((n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-(n-1)^\frac{1}{3})((n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}+(n-1)^\frac{1}{3})$

Comment: How about difference of cubes?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:[n-1,n+1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$. Then from Mean value theorem (Lagrange’a) exist $\xi\in (n-1,n+1)$ such that:

$$\frac{f(n+1)-f(n-1)}{n+1-(n-1)}=f'(\xi)$$

but (check it out)
$$\frac{2}{3 \sqrt[3]{n+1} }\le f'(\xi)\le \frac{2}{3 \sqrt[3]{n-1} } $$

so

$$\frac{4}{3 \sqrt[3]{n+1} }\le f(n+1)-f(n-1 )\le \frac{4}{3 \sqrt[3]{n-1} } $$

$$\frac{4}{3 \sqrt[3]{n+1} }\le (n+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(n-1 )^{\frac{2}{3}}\le \frac{4}{3 \sqrt[3]{n-1} } $$

now You can aplay Squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$n=\frac{1}{t}$ $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{{(1+t)}^{2/3}-{(1-t)}^{2/3}}{t^{2/3}}$$  Now apply L-Hospitals rule.. to get $$\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt[3]{1+t}}+\frac{t}{\sqrt[3]{1-t}}\right)=?$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(n+1)^{2/3} -(n-1)^{2/3}=\frac{(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2}{(n+1)^{4/3}+(n+1)^{2/3}(n-1)^{2/3}+(n-1)^{4/3}}
\\=\frac{n}{n^{4/3}}\frac4{(1+n^{-1})^{4/3}+(1-n^{-2})^{2/3}+(1-n^{-1})^{4/3}}\to 0$$

Comment: You left a $(1+n^{-1})^{2/3}$ on the second term of the denominator on the second line

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio: fixed, thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did in the second line?

Comment: @Aditya: I pulled $n^{4/3}$ out.

Comment: No the one above that

Comment: @Aditya: second means first, then ? Conjugate trinomial.

Comment: You mean something like $a^3-b^3$?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression almost looks like the symetric derivative of $f(x)=x^{2/3} $, so you have :

$$(n+1)^{2/3}-(n-1)^{2/3}\sim_{\infty}2\times\frac{2}{3}n^{-1/3} $$

Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{2/3}-(n-1)^{2/3}=0 $

edit : $$(n+1)^{2/3}-(n-1)^{2/3}= n^{2/3}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2/3} -\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2/3}\right)\\
=n^{2/3}\left(1+\frac{2}{3n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) -1+\frac{2}{3n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\
=\frac{4}{3}n^{-1/3}+o\left(n^{-1/3}\right) $$

Comment: "Almost looks like" is *very* far from the idea of a mathematical proof.

Comment: "almost looks like" as intuition, I'll edit it using taylor expansion, it works

Answer (score 1):

Set $\dfrac1n=y\implies y\to0^+$ to find

$$F=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{(1+y)^{2/3}-(1-y)^{2/3}}y$$

Now rationalize the numerator using $a^3-b^3=(a-b)\cdot (?)$
to find

$$F=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{(1+y)^2-(1-y)^2}y\cdot\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac1{(1+y)^{4/3}+(1+y)^{2/3}(1-y)^{2/3}+(1+y)^{4/3}}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor expansion

$$(1+\epsilon)^{2\over 3}= 1+{2\over 3}\epsilon +o(\epsilon)$$

We can write with $\epsilon ={1\over n}$

$$(n+1)^{2\over 3}-(n-1)^{2\over 3}=n^{2\over 3}\left(1+{2\over 3}\epsilon-1+{2\over 3}\epsilon+o(\epsilon)\right)={4\over 3}n^{-{1\over 3}}+o\left(n^{-{1\over 3}}\right)$$

And this quantity at $+\infty$ has limit $0$